# Piping multiple inputs to FFMPEG through Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

How do you pipe multiple byte files to ffmpeg through Python?
I have two files (fileA, fileB) that are different inputs to some ffmpeg command.

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

with open('fileA.yuv', 'rb') as f:
    fileA = f.read()

with open('fileB.yuv', 'rb') as f:
    fileB = f.read()   

input_string = """ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s:v 50x50 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24 -i pipe: -f rawvideo -s:v 50x50 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24 -i pipe:  ###REMAINDER OF COMMAND """

result = run(input_string, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, input=???) #What to put as input here?
result = result.stderr.splitlines() #Returns result of command
```

Comment: ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 ... something like that will be the form... but I don’t think you are going to get 2 pipes into ffmpeg, unless it works with FIFO’s

Comment: The problem is passing bytes (fileA and fileB) to an ffmpeg command through python

Comment: If you have the files then just specify them as files, if you have to stream them, the you could use UDP or similar, even on localhost.

Comment: I'm using this as a part of a Neural Network, and writing the result to file and then reading it back through ffmpeg is creating a serious bottleneck. I'm hoping theres a way to pipe the variables across to ffmpeg so I won't have to read/write from disk.

Comment: Is the bottleneck because of lag from waiting for it to finish or throughput?

Comment: bottleneck is due to a bit of both, the number of files are quite large, so I'm just trying to minimize any time that I could.